# How i can close all activities of my android app in background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-background

I created an android app and i want to start my app at the MainActivity every time my app is launched? That is if my app is at activity B and the user press the home key, then when the app is launched again, it starts at MainActivity instead of activity B? how i can do that ?

Comment: Please post what you tried to do. Why can't you create an intent to go back to the main activity?

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag for exactly this purpose. In the `<activity>` declaration for your `MainActivity` add:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

This will cause the app to start at `MainActivity` whenever it is relaunched.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this -

1. In your activity B override the 'onPause' method and add 'finish()'
2. In your manifest file where you have added `<activity>` tag for your activity B, you can add 'android:noHistory=true'. Check this link to understand more - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

I hope this will solve your issue.